# Quotient of measurable functions is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I need to show that if $f,g : X \to \mathbb{R}$ are measurables with respect to  the $\sigma$-algebra $S$ of $X$, and $g(x) \neq 0,  \forall x \in X$, then $f/g: X \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable.
So far what i got is:
I need to show that
{$x \in X: (f/g)(x) \leq c$} $\in S$.

1. First Proof: {$x \in X: (f/g)(x) < c$} $\in S$

   Without loss of generality I can write this set as

$$\{x \in X: f(x) < c \cdot g(x)\}
\implies
\exists q \in \mathbb{Q}: \{x \in X: f(x) < q < c \cdot g(x)\}
\implies \bigcup_q [ \{x \in X: f(x) < q\} \cap \{x \in X: q < c \cdot g(x)\} ] 
$$
Here's where i'm stuck. I know that $\{x \in X: f(x) < q \} \in S$ but, how do i prove that $\{x \in X: q < c \cdot g(x)\} \in S$ ?

I'm thinking the rest of the proof isn't that complicated, but if someone has more ideas, better!

Comment: Hint: if $f\colon Y\to Z$ and $g\colon X\to Y$ are measurable maps between measurable spaces, then so is $f\circ g$. A continuous function between topological spaces is a fortiori measurable with respect to Borel $\sigma$-algebras (namely, Borel measurable).

Comment: You can't write this set as that what you wrote wlog because g could be negative, so when you multiply to get $g$ on the other side, you would have to flip the sign...

Answer (score 1):

If $g$ is a measurable function then $\forall c\in \mathbb{R}, c\ne 0$, we have $c*g$ measurable. Moreover ${x \in X: g(x)> \frac{q}{c}}$ which is measurable.